# Kafka Connect - Kafka not able to find ElasticsearchSinkConnector

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I am hosting confluent kafka connector to index data from Kafka to S3 and Elasticsearch simultaneously. I am deploying it in Kubernetes environment, I am encountering the following issues recently :-

```
 ERROR Plugin class loader for connector: 'io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector' was not found. Returning: org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader@7a5b769b (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader) [pool-7-thread-1]
```

Not sure what i am missing over here, i checked the below jars they are present in the lib folder of the pod.

```
kafka-connect-elasticsearch-5.3.1.jar
kafka-connect-s3-5.3.1.jar
```

And the custom build jar placed at plugin path i.e

```
s3-sink-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

The confusing thing is the s3 connector works find with same setup and data can be seen in s3 bucket.
Any inputs/pointers which could help me in debugging the issue or resolving it will be great.

Advance thanks for any help.

Ashit

Comment: What's `plugin.path` set to? Also are you aware you're using pretty old versions of those plugins?

Comment: plugin path is set to plugin.path=/opt/kafka/plugins.
I understand that, this system has been there for sometime. I can't upgrade untill I understand the problem because of which this is failing.

Comment: where are the JAR files? Are they under a subfolder of `/opt/kafka/plugins` ?

Comment: Only the custom jar s3-sink-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar is available in the plugins path. All other jars are available in libs folder.

Answer (score 0):

For Kafka Connect to pick up plugins they should be one of the folders listed in `plugin.path`. If they are elsewhere then they won't be registered by the Kafka Connect worker.

ref: https://docs.confluent.io/home/connect/userguide.html#connect-installing-plugins